# How to take formatted input from ifstream

Tags: c++

I have a text file with a set of names formatted in the following way:

```
"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH"
```

and so on. I want to open the file using *ifstream* and read the names into a string array (without quotes, commas). I somehow managed to do it by checking the input stream character by character. Is there an easier way to take this formatted input?

EDIT: 
I heard that you can use something like 
fscanf (f, "\"%[a-zA-Z]\",", str);
in C, but is there such a method for ifstream?

Comment: You could look into [Boost.Spirit.Qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi.html). It probably requires some effort to learn, but once you got it, tasks as this are supposedly quite simple.

Comment: `fscanf` in C is not going to do what you think it would: there is no regex-like stuff in the standard [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) format string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That input should be parsable with `std::getline` or `std::regex_token_iterator` (though the latter is shooting sparrows with artillery).

Examples:

---

## Regex

**Quick and dirty, yet heavyweight solution** (using boost so most compilers eat this)

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const std::string s = "\"MARY\",\"PATRICIA\",\"LINDA\",\"BARBARA\",\"ELIZABETH\"";

    boost::regex re("\"(.*?)\"");
    for (boost::sregex_token_iterator it(s.begin(), s.end(), re, 1), end; 
         it != end; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
MARY
PATRICIA
LINDA
BARBARA
ELIZABETH
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
boost::regex re(",");
for (boost::sregex_token_iterator it(s.begin(), s.end(), re, -1), end;
```

to let it split along commas (note also the -1) or other regexes.

---

## getline

**`getline` solution** (whitespace allowed)

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str ("\"MARY\",\"PATRICIA\",\"LINDA\",\"BARBARA\",\"ELIZABETH\"");

    std::string curr;
    while (std::getline (ss, curr, ',')) {
        size_t from = 1 + curr.find_first_of ('"'),
               to   =     curr.find_last_of ('"');
        std::cout << curr.substr (from, to-from) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output is the same.

---

## getline

**`getline` solution** (whitespace not allowed)

The loop becomes almost trivial:

```
    std::string curr;
    while (std::getline (ss, curr, ',')) {
        std::cout << curr.substr (1, curr.length()-2) << std::endl;
    }
```

---

## homebrew solution

**Least wasteful w.r.t. performance** (especially when you wouldn't store those strings, but iterators or indices instead)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const std::string str ("\"MARY\",\"PATRICIA\",\"LINDA\",\"BARBARA\",\"ELIZABETH\"");        

    size_t i = 0;
    while (i != std::string::npos) {
        size_t begin  = str.find ('"', i) + 1, // one behind initial '"'
               end    = str.find ('"', begin),
               comma  = str.find (',', end);
        i = comma;

        std::cout << str.substr(begin, end-begin) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to parse the above text with getline?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That second getline solution is simply cool. :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no tokenizer in the STL. But if you are willing to use boost, there's a very good [tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) class there. Other than that, character by character is your best C++ way of addressing it (unless you are willing to go the C route, and use [`strtok_t`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtok_r.3.asp) on your raw `char *` strings).

Answer (score 1):

A simple tokenizer should do the trick; no need for something heavy-weight like regular expressions. C++ doesn't have a built-in one, but it's easy enough to write. Here's one which I myself stole off the internet so long ago I don't even remember who wrote it, so apologies for the blatant plagiarism:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string>
tokenize(const std::string & str, const std::string & delimiters)
{
  std::vector<std::string> tokens;

  // Skip delimiters at beginning.
  std::string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);

  // Find first "non-delimiter".
  std::string::size_type pos     = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);

  while (std::string::npos != pos || std::string::npos != lastPos)
  {
    // Found a token, add it to the vector.
    tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));

    // Skip delimiters.  Note the "not_of"
    lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);

    // Find next "non-delimiter"
    pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
  }

  return tokens;
}
```

Usage:  `std::vector<std::string> words = tokenize(line, ",");`

Comment: Regular expressions are heavy. As is this tokenizer regarding the input, and it does not peel off the quotation marks.

Comment: @phresnel: Quotation-mark stripping can be added by saying `str.substr(lastPos + 1, pos - lastPos -1)` I suppose, but if the quotation marks are supposed to escape commas inside the tokens, then you're right and something more powerful is needed.

Comment: Btw, root of this was mabye http://oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/CPPHOWTO/Volume/C++Programming-HOWTO-7.html . But also maybe http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/quote926566 . Or one of http://www.google.de/#q=%2F%2F+Find+first+"non-delimiter" .

Comment: From the input the just seem to quote the names. Next question would be whether whitespace is possible or. Hence there's also some confusion in my post.

Comment: @phresnel: Thanks! [This](http://oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/CPPHOWTO/Volume/C++Programming-HOWTO-7.html) really looks like it was the source! I remember modifying it to return by value rather than to modify a reference argument.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, because I was interested, I worked out how to do this using [`Boost.Spirit.Qi`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi.html):

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
  // our test-string
  std::string data("\"MARY\",\"PATRICIA\",\"LINDA\",\"BARBARA\"");
  // this is where we will store the names
  std::vector<std::string> names;
  // parse the string
  phrase_parse(data.begin(), data.end(), 
           ( lexeme['"' >> +(char_ - '"') >> '"'] % ',' ),
           space, names);
  // print what we have parsed
  std::copy(names.begin(), names.end(), 
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

To check if an error occurred during parsing, simply store the iterators over the string in variables, and compare them afterwards. If they are equal, the whole string was matched, if not, the begin-iterator will point to the error site.